# How to run 2 methods simultaneously in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, start-job

I've got two functions, each of which I want to run in the background monitoring user behavior. The functions themselves work fine; however, I cannot seem to figure out how to invoke both of them to do work at the same time. In UNIX I would simply use fork() and be done with it, but I am struggling with PS.

```
#start-job -ScriptBlock $(func1) 
#start-job -ScriptBlock $(func2)
```

Because the functions each run in an infinite while, the second line is not actually getting called, only the first function is actually doing any work.

I have tried using start-job, invoke-command, start-process, and the start method in [diagnostics.process]. My gut tells me that I am not correctly understanding what start-job does, because if it did run func1 in a background process, then there's no reason this top level script should be blocked. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing your subexpression syntax `$()` with an actual scriptblock `{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax `${function:Function-Name}` to reference the definition of a function:

```
$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:func1}
$job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:func2}
```

Comment: Why the function need to be initialized in the InitializationScript?

Comment: @RanadipDutta If the function is already defined in the script, it's unnecessary to initialize it.  Both solutions will work depending on the use-case

Comment: @RanadipDutta  `{func}` will refer to a command local to the scope of the scriptblock itself, passing a reference to the `$function:` scope will copy the function definition from the calling scope

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I got it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does referencing the function definition make the scriptblock syntax unnecessary? @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, as you can see I'm passing the function reference _in place of_ a scriptblock literal - this means it also works the exact same way when starting remote jobs

Comment: Selecting this answer as it seems it would be the simplest solution, however, I ended up placing each function in its own script and used start-process instead.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should use script block to call the function inside.

Secondly, the function has to be declared in the *InitializationScript* block else Start-job won't understand which function to call.

try something like this:

```
start-job -InitializationScript {
    #--Define function1 here
    } -ScriptBlock {func1} 

start-job -InitializationScript {
#define your  function2 here
} -ScriptBlock {func2}
```